# word or phrase for a smell that sparks nebulous memories of times or places past

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, vocabulary

I sometimes catch a whiff of something that reminds me very strongly, but very vaguely, of a time in my past. Different whiffs for different times. It's not a single identifiable smell and a single identifiable memory (i.e. chicken soup --> that time in Grade 10 when I had mononucleosis and my aunt took care of me). It's more of a vague smell that takes you back to a general time in your life.

How would you describe this? I'm open to both scientific and creative expressions of this phenomenon.

---

Allow me to add that this is not deliberate nor always positive. And I am not asking broadly about remembering the past, but about how *smell*, in particular, sparks a *sense* of past time or places.

Comment: Interesting question- have definitely experienced this- whenever I pass a specific dumpster, I feel like I'm back in camp, for example. Curious to see if anyone will come up with the word for it....

Comment: this is clearly _nosetalgia_

Comment: It may indicate nostalgia in some cases, but it is not nostalgia, per se. Nostalgia does not, by definition, include smell. Also, nostalgia is positive, but what I'm looking for is not necessarily positive or negative.

Comment: Evocative; please see my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Redolent** would be useful in this case.

Its origins are in a word simply meaning [to give an odor](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=redolent&allowed_in_frame=0), and it now is used most commonly to describe an evocative smell, and often one that triggers nostalgia.

Modern usage requires it to be attributed to something, either an item the smell reminds you of ("redolent of ripe cherries") or more figuratively of a memory :

> “[T]he very color of the air in the place I was born was different, the smell of the earth was special, redolent with memories of my parents.” -*Soseki Natsume*

It is generally used in a more positive, nostalgic sense but is not required to be.

Comment: To modern ears, the association with smell has probably disappeared entirely; still, this is quite a nice choice of words.

Comment: Thanks Michael, and welcome to the site. I think your response is great.

Answer (score 9):

It could be an [evocative](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/evocative) smell.

Comment: Indeed, smell is our most evocative sense, according to a [book promoter press release](http://www.reuters.com/article/2007/10/08/us-smells-desire-idUSN0430075020071008) that slipped into the Reuters feed a few years back.

Answer (score 6):

In French there is an expression for that "la madeleine de Proust"
The smell of a madeleine (the cake) made the writer Marcel Proust remember old events.
See the article on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeleine_%28cake%29#Literary_reference)

Comment: Indeed, in English we often speak of a memory-triggering sensation as being *Proustian*.

Answer (score 3):

**Nostalgia**

> - a sentimental longing or wistful affection for the past, typically for a period or place with happy personal associations.

Additional [source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/science/humanbody/mind/articles/intelligenceandmemory/nostalgicsmells.shtml) on Nostalgic Smells

**Olfactic Memory** could also be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Reminiscent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reminiscent) :

> - tending to remind :

also [suggestive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestive):

> - bringing thoughts, memories, or feelings into the mind.
> - stimulating further thought

Comment: Thanks Josh61; however, "reminiscence" doesn't - by definition - include the concept of smell. I'm not talking simply about remembering and recalling, but of being prompted involuntarily by smell.

Comment: @rusty, then clearly you want *remini-**scent***.

Comment: @DanBron - nice pun :))!!

Comment: @Rusty Tuba ..not sure there is a smell specific term, in the meantime I leave it here  and see what other user suggest!!

Comment: Bravo @DanBron, Bravo! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might mean synesthesia.  Baudelaire's poems - particularly 'Correspondances' - and (perhaps more famously, outside France) Proust explored this phenomenon.  In the former case, certain perfumes transported the poet back to his past.  In the latter, Proust famously remembered his past as he dunked madeleines in his tea.  Voilà.

Comment: Looks like a solid first answer. The only thing I might recommend is to cite a definition from a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Evocative

Evocative refers to something that 'evokes' or brings up something, it implies memories being triggered.

Reminding one of something pleasant.

- An evocative scent.
- The evocative scent of jasmine filled the air, instantly reminding him of her.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evocative

Comment: The same answer was already posted almost ten years ago.

Comment: @jsw29 This is a better version of that answer though. (I initially had the same reaction and then had second thoughts.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Yes, I believe this is intended to be an evergreen site, jsw29? Intended to be of benefit to future generations.