# What do you call the state, that when you see something or somebody or something is accruing reminds you something else even though unrelated?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Sometimes it feels like what is accruing at the present time  is attached to something else, every time you hear or smell something or  see something accruing reminds you the situation that you have been or experienced longtime ago, so what do you call it?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: [Word for a sudden memory triggered by a sense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55324/word-for-a-sudden-memory-triggered-by-a-sense)

Comment: Related article: [Brain's Link Between Sounds, Smells and Memory Revealed](http://www.livescience.com/8426-brain-link-sounds-smells-memory-revealed.html)

Answer (score 3):

A [flashback](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Flashback):  (from TFD)

> - a vivid memory that arises spontaneously or is provoked by an experience.
> - an experience that has characteristics of an earlier experience.
>
>   - She added, "I was worried sick when Howie came out here, like maybe he'd get a flashback of us together and be in love with me or something stupid."

or a [deja vu;](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0+Vu)

> - An impression of having seen or experienced something before:
>
>   - Old-timers watched the stock-market crash with a distinct sense of deja vu.

Comment: Very good. I couldn't make any sense out of the OQ myself.

Comment: in my opinion "flashback" is a common word  and closer to essence of my question, so I will use it .

Answer (score 0):

For "urelated situations, I'd go for **"an (false) association"**

> association
>
> - a feeling, memory, or thought that is connected to a person, place, or thing [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/association)
> - "Association" in psychology refers to a connection between conceptual entities or mental states that results from the similarity between those states or their proximity in space or time. [Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(psychology))

Comment: Why is it false? If it's associated, it's associated.

Comment: @JohnLawler  The OP says the situations are unrelated.

Comment: As far as the OP knows. That just means the OP didn't notice everything. Any association dragged from memory got in the memory somehow, and most of them feel unassociated, until we trace the connections.

Comment: @JohnLawler  The definition of "association" includes similarity. As the OP mentions "unrelated situations", I thought "false association" would be a better fit. Do you think I should remove "false"?

Comment: It's a suggestion; leave it be. It's just that "similarity" is not a very precise word. After all, why is a raven like a writing-desk?